# Controller class not loading for spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to do some sample applications. But when i tried to display a view with nothing in it, the output i am getting is like "The requested resource () is not available." Please correct me where i was wrong..

WebContent/index.jsp

```
<% 
System.out.println("--inside index--");
response.sendRedirect("newUser.jav"); %>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>xHaiSpring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jav</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver"
        p:prefix="/JSP/" p:suffix=".jsp">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

controller file

```
package com.mycontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/newUser", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newUserForm()
    {
            System.out.println("inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("registerUser");
    }

}
```

And i have a registerUser.jsp in  WebContent/JSP/ which is a blank jsp page

What is the problem? Why i am not getting to that controller file?

Comment: Can you post all of the error message?

Comment: actually my console is printing that "--inside index--". and no other errors is displaying. And the browser displays the message "requested resource is not available"

Comment: Could it be that your DispatcherServlet is mapped to `*.jav`, but your Controller is mapped to `/newUser`?

Comment: @ftr i think hats not the cause. The *.jav is there to invoke the dispatcher servlet and /newUser is which i gives in index file.

Comment: thanks friends. Actually the problem was i had missed the <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycontroller"/>

Answer (score 1):

what is the location of your controller class?

add base package in your aplication context xml file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sparkle" />
```

also try

```
<% 
System.out.println("--inside index--");
response.sendRedirect("jsp/newUser.jav"); %>
```

in your jsp

Comment: I got it correctly. It was only that because i hadnt put base-package declaration. And neednt have the response.sendRedirect("jsp/newUser.jav");
for it will take automatically to that file by dispatcher.
anyway thanks for ur suggessions..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) then use to define this

```
   <property name="mappings"><props> <prop key="/url.com">controllerName</prop> 
<bean id="controllerName" class="controllerclass"> </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only getting "--inside index--" on console and not "inside controller" the problem seems to be the request is not reaching the controller.

On line

```
response.sendRedirect("newUser.jav"); %>
```

try pre-pending '/' to ur query.

Also, have you tried using "/*.jav" below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jav</url-pattern> // have you tried /*.jav 
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have few mistakes here, or at least it appears so.

1) First of all, in `UserController` you return `new ModelAndView("registerUser")`. That means that registered view resolver should look for a view with name `registerUser`.
Your code registers view resolver with id `viewResolver` pointing to `/JSP/` with `.jsp` suffix. Please modify it to `WEB-INF/views`, that way they won't be easily accessed outside of Spring (which is generally a good security precaution).
Now, your view should be then located in `WebContent/WEB-INF/views/registerUser.jsp`. Please note that the name of the view is used to locate particular view file.

2) In controller you set `@RequestMapping(value="/newUser", method=RequestMethod.GET)` but you are explicitly telling Spring only to map requests with `*.jav` path (in `web.xml`). So any call to `/newUser` will not be even handled by Spring. Make sure to use `<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>` mapping for servlet.

3) It looks like you want to set up Spring without having some basic knowledge about how does it work. Please make sure to read some decent tutorial available on the internet and refer to  Spring's reference for in depth description. Otherwise you are asking for trouble. Using a framework needs some learning curve, or you will get frustrated pretty soon.